# Create a User-Profile Mini-Game

Tags: popularity-contest, game

Yesterday, I stumbled on a very clever thing.

[image: minitech's tic-tac-toe profile game]

Yes, that's a [working implementation of Tic-Tac-Toe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/707111/minitech) on a user profile page, from `@minitech`.  Of course, the moment I saw it, I had to [reverse engineer his idea and one-up him](https://stackoverflow.com/users/116614/mellamokb) :P

[image: mellamokb's towers of hanoi profile game]

Here's my own example embedded directly in the post.  It's a tad buggy due to a couple of implementation details I haven't worked out a good solution for.  Sometimes after you click a peg, it doesn't update properly until another page refresh:

### Towers of Hanoi

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]

[Reset](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5933/create-a-user-profile-mini-game?reset)

### Can you do better?

- Create a working game in your posted answer (or your user profile page).  This is done via appropriately configuring a webserver you own (or writing a program that acts as a webserver), and embedding content from it in a post, using the referer to determine what commands the user is giving to the game.
- Coolest idea (most votes) wins the competition, by Canada Day (Sunday, July 1, 2012 @ 11:59 PM EST)
- In the event of a tie, the older answer wins.

Comment: +1 Simple, but brilliant idea! BTW - for the deadline I think you mean *June* 2, 2012.

Comment: Short deadline + already answered your own question = downvote.

Comment: @boothby: I was actually thinking about deleting my answer.  The intention was to provide a concrete example, not to win the contest (or votes, I don't greatly care about rep).  Can you provide some constructive suggestions to the competition?  What would you like the deadline to be?  How should the spec be changed to motivate you to participate?

Comment: I just noticed that minitech's AI can't play a perfect game of tic-tac-toe. Play center, bottom-left, top-center, center-right, center-left.

Comment: @mellamokb, the later you make the deadline (within reason), the more answers and more variety you'll get.  I'd say set it for Canada Day.

Comment: @boothby, There was just a recent SE blogpost reminding people that they are encouraged to answer their own questions.

Comment: @breadbox: That was probably more relevant for SO than here.  I agree with `boothby` that my posting an answer could be seen as an unfair way to win/get votes, so I removed it and placed my example inside the question instead.

Comment: @boothby: No I agree, I'll extend it out some more.  I didn't want to make the contest too long, but I think end of June is fine.  I'll update.

Comment: Maybe I'm being stupid, but none of these work for me (Chrome 19.0.1084.46 beta-m)

Comment: I'm on Chrome 19.0.1084.52 and have no issue.  What are you seeing?

Comment: Neither example works in Firefox 12 on Windows 7.  What are the browser requirements?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: working fine on FF 12.0 & Windows 7 here, could you post more details about what's not working?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: If you look at some of the examples below, they should all work because they have a single image.  As I mention in my post, since I have 4 images, there are flukey things that happen, where it doesn't appear to work but it actually has.  My updates are applied specifically when the image with text (first image) is loaded.  If that image is loaded last due to how the browser loads the images, it will *appear* that nothing has happened, but the state of the game actually has changed if you reload the page (i.e., click the question title to reload) or click another peg.

Comment: You might have to allow 3rd party cookies to get Hangman and Maze working (my game should work fine without it; I recommend blocking them again afterwards for privacy reasons). ChristopheD's and my game also need a browser that allows [svg in img tags](http://caniuse.com/#feat=svg-img)

Comment: @copy: I switched to PNG output for compatibility purposes, and the 3rd party cookie (which was really only a problem with IE with most browser's default settings) should be solved now as well afaik.

Comment: @ChristopheD I think P3P policies only work for IE and Safari. I can't play Maze or Hangman without changing my settings at least (Chromium 17)

Comment: Yeah, this was randomly thrown together. Chess coming up next, guys! Also, nice job on the towers of Hanoi. It looks better.

Comment: @minitech: I especially liked your secret message in TTT if you try to hack :P

Answer (score 28, accepted):

### Conway's Game of Life

[image]

[+1 generation](/questions/5933/create-a-user-profile-mini-game?next#answer-5946) -
[+5 generations](/questions/5933/create-a-user-profile-mini-game?next=5#answer-5946) -
[zoom in](/questions/5933/create-a-user-profile-mini-game?zoomin#answer-5946) -
[zoom out](/questions/5933/create-a-user-profile-mini-game?zoomout#answer-5946)

Load pattern: 
[random](/questions/5933/create-a-user-profile-mini-game?random#answer-5946) -
[glider](/questions/5933/create-a-user-profile-mini-game?pattern=glider#answer-5946) - 
[gunstar](/questions/5933/create-a-user-profile-mini-game?pattern=gunstar#answer-5946) -
[snail](/questions/5933/create-a-user-profile-mini-game?pattern=snail#answer-5946) -
[lwss](/questions/5933/create-a-user-profile-mini-game?pattern=lwss#answer-5946) -
[lightspeedoscillator1](/questions/5933/create-a-user-profile-mini-game?pattern=lightspeedoscillator1#answer-5946) -
[tumbler](/questions/5933/create-a-user-profile-mini-game?pattern=tumbler#answer-5946)

Used Python and SVG output. I have tried using single pixels at first (so you could toggle single cells), but it did not work out, because the browser does not load images in order. Also, much bigger patterns are possible like this without crashing my webserver.

**Update:**

I had some fun with python and added several features and improvements:

- Added HUD with population count, zoom and name
- Patterns in the rle format can now be loaded ([long list](https://copy.sh/life/examples/list), [via](http://conwaylife.com/wiki/Main_Page)) using the `pattern` parameter (e.g. `?pattern=glider`). The filesize is limited to 1.5kB
- Can forward n generations, limited to 5 at a time, using the `next` parameter
- Slightly improved algorithm. It's not really fast though, I want this to stay simple
- It also works standalone now (uses either referer or its own query string):
  https://copy.sh/fcgi-bin/life2.py?pattern=gosperglidergun

```py
sessions = {}

WIDTH = 130
HEIGHT = 130
RULE = (3,), (2, 3)

def read_pattern(filename, offset_x, offset_y):

    filename = PATH + filename + '.rle.gz'

    try:
        if os.stat(filename).st_size > 1500:
            return ['pattern too big', set()]
    except OSError as e:
        return ['could not find pattern', set()]

    file = gzip.open(filename)

    x, y = offset_x, offset_y
    name = ''
    pattern_string = ''
    field = []

    for line in file:
        if line[0:2] == '#N':
            name = line[2:-1]
        elif line[0] != '#' and line[0] != 'x':
            pattern_string += line[:-1]

    for count, chr in re.findall('(\d*)(b|o|\$|!)', pattern_string):
        count = int(count) if count else 1

        if chr == 'o':
            for i in range(x, x + count):
                field.append( (i, y) )
            x += count
        elif chr == 'b':
            x += count
        elif chr == '$':
            y += count
            x = offset_x
        elif chr == '!':
            break

    file.close()

    return [name, set(field)]



def next_generation(field, n):

    for _ in range(n):

        map = {}

        for (x, y) in field:
            for (i, j) in ( (x-1, y-1), (x, y-1), (x+1, y-1), (x-1, y), (x+1, y), (x-1, y+1), (x, y+1), (x+1, y+1) ):
                map[i, j] = map[i, j] + 1 if (i, j) in map else 1

        field = [
            (x, y)
            for x in range(0, WIDTH)
            for y in range(0, HEIGHT)
            if (x, y) in map
            if ( (map[x, y] in RULE[1]) if (x, y) in field else (map[x, y] in RULE[0]) )
        ]

    return field


def life(env, start):


    if 'REMOTE_ADDR' in env:
        client_ip = env['REMOTE_ADDR']
    else:
        client_ip = '0'

    if not client_ip in sessions:
        sessions[client_ip] = read_pattern('trueperiod22gun', 10, 10) + [2]

    session = sessions[client_ip]

    if 'HTTP_REFERER' in env:
        query = urlparse.parse_qs(urlparse.urlparse(env['HTTP_REFERER']).query, True)
    elif 'QUERY_STRING' in env:
        query = urlparse.parse_qs(env['QUERY_STRING'], True)
    else:
        query = None

    timing = time.time()

    if query:
        if 'next' in query:
            try:
                count = min(5, int(query['next'][0]))
            except ValueError as e:
                count = 1
            session[1] = set( next_generation(session[1], count) )
        elif 'random' in query:
            session[0:2] = 'random', set([ (random.randint(0, WIDTH), random.randint(0, HEIGHT)) for _ in range(800) ])
        elif 'pattern' in query:
            filename = query['pattern'][0]
            if filename.isalnum():
                session[0:2] = read_pattern(filename, 10, 10)
        elif 'zoomin' in query:
            session[2] += 1
        elif 'zoomout' in query and session[2] > 1:
            session[2] -= 1

    timing = time.time() - timing

    start('200 Here you go', [
        ('Content-Type', 'image/svg+xml'), 
        ('Cache-Control', 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0'), 
        ('Expires', 'Tue, 01 Jan 2000 12:12:12 GMT')
    ])

    pattern_name, field, zoom = session

    yield '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'
    yield '<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">'
    yield '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" baseProfile="full" width="400px" height="200px">'
    yield '<!-- finished in %f -->' % timing
    yield '<text x="0" y="10" style="font-size:10px">Population: %d</text>' % len(field)
    yield '<text x="100" y="10" style="font-size:10px">Zoom: %d</text>' % zoom
    yield '<text x="180" y="10" style="font-size:10px; font-weight:700">%s</text>' % pattern_name
    yield '<line x1="0" y1="15" x2="666" y2="15" style="stroke:#000; stroke-width:1px" />'

    for (x, y) in field:
        yield '<rect x="%d" y="%d" width="%d" height="%d"/>' % (zoom * x, zoom * y + 20, zoom, zoom)

    yield '</svg>'


from flup.server.fcgi import WSGIServer
import random
import re
import gzip
import os
import urlparse
import time

WSGIServer(life).run()
```

You can take my code as a template for further python fastcgi submissions.

Comment: +1 Awesome!  One suggestion: append `#5946` to your links, and it will jump back to your post after every update.

Comment: hmm.. at least it worked when i tried it.. ah. because in Towers of Hanoi you're always clicking on different pegs.  hmm

Comment: @mellamokb it works, but you can't click the same link twice now

Comment: Ya, I just realized that lol.  Guess you can provide a disclaimer that when doing next generation, just press F5 for future iterations instead of clicking the `next` link again and again after the first time.

Comment: Regarding `browser does not load images in order`, that's the implementation detail that is troubling me.  I'm thinking there needs to be a way to have the first image requested (which ever one it is) do all the session updates, and the rest of the images just load.  But it's difficult to track this on the server side, especially if the requests look identical.

Comment: It would be really awesome if someone could make this a dynamically-rendered animated GIF.

Comment: Accepted your answer as it has the most votes.  Although to be fair, that's probably partly because yours was the oldest answer :)

Comment: @mellamokb thanks. In my opinion you don't really need to accept answers on this platform, because it looks as if the challenge is closed

Answer (score 36):

## C# - Stack Exchange Hangman

Guess names of Stack Exchange websites in this Hangman game:

[image]
<sub>(source: [apphb.com](https://game24.apphb.com/hangman))</sub>

[`A`](/questions/5933/create-a-user-profile-mini-game?_hangman_A_#answer-5954)
[`B`](/questions/5933/create-a-user-profile-mini-game?_hangman_B_#answer-5954)
[`C`](/questions/5933/create-a-user-profile-mini-game?_hangman_C_#answer-5954)
[`D`](/questions/5933/create-a-user-profile-mini-game?_hangman_D_#answer-5954)
[`E`](/questions/5933/create-a-user-profile-mini-game?_hangman_E_#answer-5954)
[`F`](/questions/5933/create-a-user-profile-mini-game?_hangman_F_#answer-5954)
[`G`](/questions/5933/create-a-user-profile-mini-game?_hangman_G_#answer-5954)
[`H`](/questions/5933/create-a-user-profile-mini-game?_hangman_H_#answer-5954)
[`I`](/questions/5933/create-a-user-profile-mini-game?_hangman_I_#answer-5954)
[`J`](/questions/5933/create-a-user-profile-mini-game?_hangman_J_#answer-5954)
[`K`](/questions/5933/create-a-user-profile-mini-game?_hangman_K_#answer-5954)
[`L`](/questions/5933/create-a-user-profile-mini-game?_hangman_L_#answer-5954)
[`M`](/questions/5933/create-a-user-profile-mini-game?_hangman_M_#answer-5954)
[`N`](/questions/5933/create-a-user-profile-mini-game?_hangman_N_#answer-5954)
[`O`](/questions/5933/create-a-user-profile-mini-game?_hangman_O_#answer-5954)
[`P`](/questions/5933/create-a-user-profile-mini-game?_hangman_P_#answer-5954)
[`Q`](/questions/5933/create-a-user-profile-mini-game?_hangman_Q_#answer-5954)
[`R`](/questions/5933/create-a-user-profile-mini-game?_hangman_R_#answer-5954)
[`S`](/questions/5933/create-a-user-profile-mini-game?_hangman_S_#answer-5954)
[`T`](/questions/5933/create-a-user-profile-mini-game?_hangman_T_#answer-5954)
[`U`](/questions/5933/create-a-user-profile-mini-game?_hangman_U_#answer-5954)
[`V`](/questions/5933/create-a-user-profile-mini-game?_hangman_V_#answer-5954)
[`W`](/questions/5933/create-a-user-profile-mini-game?_hangman_W_#answer-5954)
[`X`](/questions/5933/create-a-user-profile-mini-game?_hangman_X_#answer-5954)
[`Y`](/questions/5933/create-a-user-profile-mini-game?_hangman_Y_#answer-5954)
[`Z`](/questions/5933/create-a-user-profile-mini-game?_hangman_Z_#answer-5954)

[`New game`](/questions/5933/create-a-user-profile-mini-game?_new_hangman_#answer-5954)

---

This was done using [ASP.NET MVC 3.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/mvc3). Here's the code of the [`Controller`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.controller?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) that does the trick:

```c#
public class HangmanController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var game = Session["hangman"] as HangmanGame ?? HangmanGame.New();

        game = ExecuteGameCommand(game);

        Session["hangman"] = game;

        var imageRenderer = new HangmanImageRenderer(game);
        return new ImageResult(imageRenderer.Render());
    }

    private HangmanGame ExecuteGameCommand(HangmanGame game)
    {
        var referrerQuery = Request.UrlReferrer != null ? Request.UrlReferrer.Query : string.Empty;

        if (referrerQuery.Contains("_new_hangman_"))
            return HangmanGame.New();

        if(game.IsOver())
            return game;

        var chosenLetter = HangmanGame.ValidLetters
            .FirstOrDefault(letter => referrerQuery.Contains(String.Format("_hangman_{0}_", letter)));

        if (chosenLetter != default(char))
            game.RegisterGuess(chosenLetter);

        return game;
    }
}
```

Other than this code, there are three more classes that I haven't included since they are pretty long and straightforward:

- `HangmanGame` - here's where the game business rules are implemented
- `HangmanImageRenderer` - the class that encapsulates all the GDI ugliness
- `ImageResult` - a custom [`ActionResult`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.actionresult?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) that is used to return a dynamically generated image

The entire code listing is available at http://pastebin.com/ccwZLknX

Comment: +1 Wow, you guys are awesome :).  Like the ideas so far!

Comment: Cool, never heard of appharbor.com.  Are you really paying to host your answer?

Comment: @mellamokb no, I'm using the Appharbor's free hosting plan. If this gets clicked a lot I guess I'll have to pay though... :)

Comment: I was going to mention if necessary, I can provide custom subdomain hosting and FTP access to my hosting site.

Comment: @mellamokb thanks, but I think this hosting will do. I was just joking about many clicks. :)

Comment: You could add the following header to make your solution work in IE (with default Medium Privacy settings, won't accept cookies from your image otherwise): `P3P: CP="CURa ADMa DEVa PSAo PSDo OUR BUS UNI PUR INT DEM STA PRE COM NAV OTC NOI DSP COR"`

Comment: @ChristopheD Wow, I wasn't even aware that this does not work on IE. Thanks a lot, I made the modification you suggested and it works fine now (at least in IE9)

Answer (score 21):

## Clojoban! [WIP]

I wanted to make a bigger game out of this to learn [Clojure](https://clojure.org/), so this took a while to pull off (and got pretty big.) I've had a lot of fun doing it, btw!

[image: Clojoban!]
[<kbd>Restart level</kbd>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5933/create-a-user-profile-mini-game?_clojoban_restart_#6383)[<kbd>New game</kbd>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5933/create-a-user-profile-mini-game?_clojoban_new_#6383)

. . [<kbd>↑</kbd>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5933/create-a-user-profile-mini-game?_clojoban_up_#6383)

[<kbd>←</kbd>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5933/create-a-user-profile-mini-game?_clojoban_left_#6383)
[<kbd>→</kbd>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5933/create-a-user-profile-mini-game?_clojoban_right_#6383) -
[<kbd>No-op*</kbd>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5933/create-a-user-profile-mini-game?_clojoban_noop_#6383)

. . [<kbd>↓</kbd>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5933/create-a-user-profile-mini-game?_clojoban_down_#6383)

**(click here if game becomes unresponsive)*

### Instructions

You are Robby [image: Robby], a hard-working robot. You work at a `FlipCo Industries` as a heavy load carrier. Your job is to move each `box` [image: A box] to a `goal` [image: A goal] spending as few steps as possible. `FlipCo`'s facilities are **DANGEROUS**. There are lots of challenges and special places to discover.

If you get stuck, click <kbd>Restart level</kbd> (but your step count won't be reset!)

---

You can also play at [Clojoban's front page](https://clojoban.herokuapp.com/) (although it kind of ruins the purpose of the challenge.) It fixes the infamous anchor problem, doesn't require cross-site cookies and you can play with your keyboard arrow keys! You can also play at [my user profile](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/4685/%C3%81lvaro-cuesta) page without the annoying anchor problem.

In Firefox the image doesn't flicker while it's loading so it's a bit more comfortable to play.

This game is FAR from completion, **Clojoban is still a work in progress**. You can see the complete sourcecode at [Clojoban's GitHub project page](https://github.com/alvaro-cuesta/clojoban). There's some info in the [README](https://github.com/alvaro-cuesta/clojoban#clojoban) about [contributing](https://github.com/alvaro-cuesta/clojoban#contributing). I need levels too! See the level format at the [example levels](https://github.com/alvaro-cuesta/clojoban/tree/master/resources/levels). You can peek at [Clojoban's issue tracker](https://github.com/alvaro-cuesta/clojoban/issues) and see what's coming next!

Comment: Now your reputation is 11 :)

Comment: @mellamokb thanks! Game is embedded now :)

Comment: Apparently this didn't get much attention. Any tips for improving?

Comment: Your answer is good, I think this question overall has stagnated.  I haven't seen much activity or votes for the last couple of days.

Comment: That's a great game! I think you should make a standalone version; I got to the third level and got rid of pressing the No-op button. :) Anyway, great work!

Comment: @w0lf there's a standalone version at [Clojoban's front page](http://clojoban.herokuapp.com/). You can even use your arrow keys to move there, which makes the game far more playable :)

Comment: @ÁlvaroCuesta Just finished it. Excellent! The ice is a great twist to the classic Sokoban. This would also be great for a mobile phone game :)

Comment: How did you get the game working in your SO -profile? The game is in image -element and then with POST -request played? I tried already the labyrithm but did not get it working in the profile :(

Comment: It appears this game has stopped working :(

Comment: @hhh look at the address bar! The SO-side querystring is read in the referer header. Persistence is handled game-side with sessions.

Comment: @mellamokbtheWise apparently it fixed itself.

Comment: You want a good level? Take a look at these: http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Sokoban they do have too many boxes though.

Answer (score 17):

### Maze

[image]
<sub>(source: [t15.org](http://phpshizzle.t15.org/sogolf_maze/maze.php))</sub>

<sub>[<kbd>New</kbd>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5933/create-a-user-profile-mini-game/6171?resetmaze#answer-6171)
[<kbd>←</kbd>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5933/create-a-user-profile-mini-game/6171?playerleft#answer-6171)
[<kbd>↑</kbd>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5933/create-a-user-profile-mini-game/6171?playerup#answer-6171)
[<kbd>↓</kbd>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5933/create-a-user-profile-mini-game/6171?playerdown#answer-6171)
[<kbd>→</kbd>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5933/create-a-user-profile-mini-game/6171?playerright#answer-6171) - 
[<kbd>Noop button</kbd>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5933/create-a-user-profile-mini-game/6171?noop#answer-6171)</sub>

I started from the PHP maze generator I found here: http://dev.horemag.net/2008/03/01/php-maze-generation-class/.

**EDIT**: changed the output to PNG instead of SVG (for better cross browser compatibility).

**EDIT 2:** added a header for fixing IE cookie compatibility. Should now work correctly in all major browsers.

The image does not refresh if you take the same direction twice (due to the anchor links). Press F5 the second time, or play the maze [on my stackoverflow profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/81179/christophed).

**EDIT 3:** Added a no-op button for easily being able to take the same direction twice (see comments below).

```php
<?php
// based upon the maze generator by Evgeni Vasilev (PHP Adaptation)
// see http://dev.horemag.net/2008/03/01/php-maze-generation-class/
class Maze
{
  var $maze = array();
  var $mx = 0;
  var $my = 0;
  var $xplayer = 1;
  var $yplayer = 1;

  function Maze($mx, $my)
  {
    $mx +=2;
    $my +=2;
    $this->mx = $mx;
    $this->my = $my;
    $dx = array( 0, 0, -1, 1 );
    $dy = array( -1, 1, 0, 0 );
    $todo = array(); 
    $todonum = 0;

    for ($x = 0; $x < $mx; ++$x){
      for ($y = 0; $y < $my; ++$y){
        if ($x == 0 || $x == $mx-1 || $y == 0 || $y == $my-1) {
          $this->maze[$x][$y] = 32;
        } else {
          $this->maze[$x][$y] = 63;
        }
      }
    }
    $x = rand(1, $mx-2); $y = rand(1, $my-2);
    $x = 1; $y = 1;
    $this->maze[$x][$y] &= ~48;
    for ($d = 0; $d < 4; ++$d){
      if (($this->maze[$x + $dx[$d]][$y + $dy[$d]] & 16) != 0) {
        $todo[$todonum++] = (($x + $dx[$d]) << 16) | ($y + $dy[$d]);
        $this->maze[$x + $dx[$d]][$y + $dy[$d]] &= ~16;
      }
    }

    while ($todonum > 0) {
      $n = rand(0, $todonum-1);
      $x = $todo[$n] >> 16;
      $y = $todo[$n] & 65535;
      $todo[$n] = $todo[--$todonum];
      do {
        $d = rand(0, 3);
      } while (($this->maze[$x + $dx[$d]][$y + $dy[$d]] & 32) != 0);
      $this->maze[$x][$y] &= ~((1 << $d) | 32);
      $this->maze[$x + $dx[$d]][$y + $dy[$d]] &= ~(1 << ($d ^ 1));
      for ($d = 0; $d < 4; ++$d){
        if (($this->maze[$x + $dx[$d]][$y + $dy[$d]] & 16) != 0) {
          $todo[$todonum++] = (($x + $dx[$d]) << 16) | ($y + $dy[$d]);
          $this->maze[$x + $dx[$d]][$y + $dy[$d]] &= ~16;
        }
      }
    }
    $this->maze[1][1] &= ~1;
    $this->maze[$mx-2][$my-2] &= ~2;
  }

  function _drawLine($img,$color, $x1, $y1, $x2, $y2)
  {
    imageline($img, $x1, $y1, $x2, $y2, $color);
  }
  
  function _drawPlayer($img, $x, $y, $r, $colorborder, $colorfill)
  {
    imagefilledellipse($img, $x, $y, $r, $r, $colorfill);
    imageellipse($img, $x, $y, $r, $r, $colorborder);
  }
  
  function _drawWin($img, $color)
  {
    imagestring($img, 5, 170, 90, "YOU WIN!", $color);
  }
  
  function movePlayerDown()
  {
    if ($this->yplayer+1 < $this->my-1 && ($this->maze[$this->xplayer][$this->yplayer] & 2) == 0)
    $this->yplayer++;
  }

  function movePlayerUp()
  {
    if ($this->yplayer-1 > 0 && ($this->maze[$this->xplayer][$this->yplayer] & 1) == 0)
      $this->yplayer--;
  }

  function movePlayerRight()
  {
    if ($this->xplayer+1 < $this->mx-1 && ($this->maze[$this->xplayer][$this->yplayer] & 8) == 0)
      $this->xplayer++;
  }  

  function movePlayerLeft()
  {
    if ($this->xplayer-1 > 0 && ($this->maze[$this->xplayer][$this->yplayer] & 4) == 0)
      $this->xplayer--;
  }  
  
  function renderImage($xs, $ys)
  {
    $off = 0;
    $w = ($this->mx*$xs)+($off*2); $h = ($this->my*$ys)+($off*2);
    $img = imagecreatetruecolor($w, $h);
    imagesetthickness($img, 2);
    $fg = imagecolorallocate($img, 0, 0, 0);
    $bg = imagecolorallocate($img, 248, 248, 248);
    $red = imagecolorallocate($img, 255, 0, 0);
    imagefill($img, 0, 0, $bg);
    if (($this->xplayer == $this->mx-2) && ($this->yplayer == $this->my-2)) {
      $this->_drawWin($img, $red);
      return $img;
    }
    
    for ($y = 1; $y < $this->my-1; ++$y) {
      for ($x = 1; $x < $this->mx-1; ++$x){
        if (($this->maze[$x][$y] & 1) != 0)
          $this->_drawLine ($img, $fg, $x * $xs + $off, $y * $ys + $off, $x * $xs + $xs + $off, $y * $ys + $off);
        if (($this->maze[$x][$y] & 2) != 0)
          $this->_drawLine ($img, $fg, $x * $xs + $off, $y * $ys + $ys + $off, $x * $xs + $xs + $off, $y * $ys + $ys + $off);
        if (($this->maze[$x][$y] & 4) != 0)
          $this->_drawLine ($img, $fg, $x * $xs + $off, $y * $ys + $off, $x * $xs + $off, $y * $ys + $ys + $off);
        if (($this->maze[$x][$y] & 8) != 0)
          $this->_drawLine ($img, $fg, $x * $xs + $xs + $off, $y * $ys + $off, $x * $xs + $xs + $off, $y * $ys + $ys + $off);
        if ($x == $this->xplayer && $y == $this->yplayer) {
          $this->_drawPlayer ($img, $x * $xs + ($xs/2), $y * $ys + ($ys/2), 14, $fg, $red);
        }
      }
    }
    return $img;
  }
}
header('P3P: CP="CURa ADMa DEVa PSAo PSDo OUR BUS UNI PUR INT DEM STA PRE COM NAV OTC NOI DSP COR"');
session_start();
$orig_url = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
if (!isset($_SESSION['maze']) || strpos($orig_url, 'resetmaze')){
    $_SESSION['maze'] = new Maze(25,10);
}
$maze = $_SESSION['maze'];
if (strpos($orig_url, 'playerdown')) { $maze->movePlayerDown(); }
if (strpos($orig_url, 'playerup')) { $maze->movePlayerUp(); }
if (strpos($orig_url, 'playerright')) { $maze->movePlayerRight(); }
if (strpos($orig_url, 'playerleft')) { $maze->movePlayerLeft(); }
$img = $maze->renderImage(16,16);
header("Content-Type: image/png");
imagepng($img);
imagedestroy($img);
?>
```

Comment: +1 Nice! for a better experience, add `#answer-6171` at the end of your links. Otherwise, no one will have enough patience to solve the maze.

Comment: @W0lf: Thanks. I thought about including the `#` links but the problem is they don't refresh the page when you take the same direction twice (which can happen in a maze ;-). I've added them now so people will have to press F5 the second time they want to take the same direction. Another option is to play it here (my SO profile: http://stackoverflow.com/users/81179/christophed)

Comment: I would fancy a simple no-operation link (refresh?) to make the update easier when trying to move twice in the same direction :)

Comment: @kaoD: Without the anchor parts (`#`) which jump to the right answer to the question (internally, without page refresh), a simple page refresh would work fine (as you can see on my linked profile where the same maze is also available). But the problem then would be that you would find yourself at the top of the page after every refresh. The real problem is that we're really limited in what we can include in an answer here on StackOverflow (for good reason off course), we can't use arbitrary Javascript for example. I have no idea about an easy way out.

Comment: You can still have the anchor and it will go straight to your post, but with a different URL (which will allow for correct gameplay.) I find the F5 method clunky.

Comment: @kaoD: the URL's are part of the `answer` here, I can't easily change them (each iteration). Or do I misunderstand? AFAIK the other solutions suffer the same shortcomings (when using anchor links to point to the right answer).

Comment: @ChristopheD I mean you just need a link to http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5933/create-a-user-profile-mini-game/6171?noop#answer-6171 and clicking it will refresh the page, keep the anchor and will let you click the same option again.

Comment: @kaoD: I've included a noop part as you suggested, but I still don't see how that would help (the second time) since I am obliged to use fixed links in my answer...

Comment: @ChristopheD wow, I'm having a hard time making it clear :P If you put that link apart (not for each of your links) the user can click it to avoid pressing F5 (which doesn't always work for me, btw.) Since the URL changes (and your game does nothing, since it's a non-operative link) you can click again the link that didn't work before!

Comment: @kaoD: sorry for begin so slow in understanding what you meant, I've added a <kbd>noop</kbd> button.

Comment: Sorry I am total noob but I tried to get a next move like this [here](http://koti.kapsi.fi/~he/SO/maze.php?playerdown), why does it not work? I am apparently misunderstanding the POST -request? I copy-pasted this code to my server with PHP support, maze [here](http://koti.kapsi.fi/~he/SO/index.php) works, but the POST -controls not working with your example, why?

Answer (score 11):

### "Simon says" game

Unfortunately, I could not get this submission in on time by the (somewhat arbitrary) deadline, but I really wanted to demonstrate animation in such a user profile game, and none of the previous submissions are animated. This game is a clone of the classic Milton Bradley game [Simon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simon_%28game%29), in which the player tries to repeat an increasingly long sequence of signals.

Information about this game, including its source code, is available at [its GitHub page](https://github.com/plstand/gifsimon). There may be occasional graphical glitches (especially on Windows computers) arising from the hackish "palette animation" that avoids the need for a graphics drawing library. The existence of these glitches can serve as a useful excuse for quickly losing this game because of terrible memory.

Additionally, the effects of high latency and limited bandwidth can make this game much more challenging than the original as well. I think that in order to get much more than five points (when the game first speeds up), you will need to determine which light flashes one more time than in the previous round rather than depending on the correct sequence (which is very hard to do).

If this game fails to work for you (it restarts every time you click a button), your browser might be blocking its cookie. I have not yet added a workaround, so for the time being, please either use Chrome, Opera, or Firefox or temporarily change your Internet Explorer or Safari cookie settings.

**Edit 2018-05-24:** At this time, I have deleted the publicly accessible Heroku instance of this app. I may or may not put the app back online at a later date. The [app's code](https://github.com/plstand/gifsimon) is still available on GitHub, so you can either run it locally or create your own Heroku app instance if you wish to play the game.

Comment: +1 That is absolutely brilliant!  Never thought of doing dynamically generated animate gifs :P